# How to set OUT param in a Mysql prepared statement?

Tags: mysql

```
PROCEDURE count_apples(OUT cnt INT)
BEGIN

   SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT count(apple) FROM tree';

   PREPARE PrepStmt1 FROM @SqlQuery;
   EXECUTE PrepStmt1;

   DEALLOCATE PREPARE PrepStmt1;

END
```

How do I set the out param to the value returned by the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a prepared statement at all, for the simple example:

```
PROCEDURE count_apples(OUT cnt INT)
BEGIN

   SET cnt = (SELECT count(apple) FROM tree);

END
```

However, if that's just an example and your query actual query is more complicated such that you do need prepared statements, then you need to use a user-defined variable to hold the result, then copy it to the `OUT` parameter, which behaves as a program variable.

```
PROCEDURE count_apples(OUT cnt INT)
BEGIN

   SET @SqlQuery = 'SET @cnt = (SELECT count(apple) FROM tree)';

   PREPARE PrepStmt1 FROM @SqlQuery;
   EXECUTE PrepStmt1;

   DEALLOCATE PREPARE PrepStmt1;

   SET cnt = @cnt;    

END
```

You can't reference *any* stored program variables (in, out, inout, declared, or otherwise) in a prepared statement -- only [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html), which begin with `@` and are completely unrelated to any program variable of the same name.

The reason you have to copy the values around is that prepared statements are scoped to the session that created them -- not the procedure.  They exist in the environment underlying the procedure rather than inside the procedure itself.  To see this in action, `PREPARE` a prepared statement in a procedure, but don't `EXECUTE` or `DEALLOCATE PREPARE` it.  Then when the procedure is done, you'll find that you can still `EXECUTE` the procedure.

For the same reason, if you `EXECUTE` stmt `USING` variables for `?` placeholders, those variables have to be `@` user-defined variables, too -- you can't use program variables there, either, because of the scope of prepared statements.